# What could I use for a tri-state control?

Tags: controls

I'm trying to think of a nice element where there are 3 states, but a simple checkbox would be a litlte overkill for what I want (I'd need two), as the states are:

- Enabled
- Default
- Disabled

But I want the user to be able to change to this at any one time and I find tri-state checkboxeIs are too difficult to figure out how to use.

What do you think is the best way to implement this? I currently am thinking of just three buttons, but there must be something really obvious that does this which I'm more than capable of programming (I'm a programmer not a UX desginer)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What's wrong with just using the standard element for choosing one of multiple options - the dropdown list (or combobox or select, depending on your technology)? Or if you want, you can use three radio buttons (but I prefer dropdowns for something like this).

Why create something with non-standard functionality when something already exists that everyone already knows how to use?

Comment: True, thanks for that. Makes a lot of sense now :)

Comment: Good answer. You could also use a segmented control although that has more limited application. See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Controls/Controls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000359-TPXREF104

Comment: @AdamSmith - that's pretty much exactly what Christofian is talking about in his answer; he just isn't calling it that very Apple-centric name.

Comment: I'm using a Bootstrap+jQuery powered Segmented control at the moment which looks very similar to what Apple are saying

Comment: The link provided by Adam is not working anymore, due to a major update from Apple. Here is the current link to Apple's Human Interface Guideline, describing the segmented control element: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/OSXHIGuidelines/ControlsSelection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000957-CH49-SW1

Answer (score 9):

I think a button with a pop-up menu would be the best answer for this. See the image below.

[image: 3 state button prototype]

You can easily create a custom control deriving from a toggle button and styling it accordingly. Depending on what technology you develop in this task may be easier or harder.

Comment: Thanks, that looks really darn good! I might create two versions and see what appeals best to people. (P.S what did you make that picture in, if it's some diagramming software I'd love to have a play with it)

Comment: I'm glad you like it, I used Photoshop to create it. :)

Answer (score 5):

Mayby something like this:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvYqAx.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

A row of buttons would work great for this purpose, and it shouldn't be that hard to make.

Comment: That's what I've got so far, I was wondering if there was anything else